# Is Encrypting/Decrypting an external USB Drive with minimal priviledge possible?

Tags: linux, luks, non-root-user, ecryptfs, veracrypt

The following situation is the case:
I want to provide my students with an easy way to protect their data securely and encrypted on an external usb drive with the zero knowledge principle in mind so that they can rest assured that they are the only ones beside the ram that at any point in time have access to their secret key.

Is this possible without granting them too many rights (no root) and if so how would one go about this endeavor the easiest way?

Compatibility with other Operating Systems is not needed by default as every student will be encouraged to use linux as a secondary OS and provided with an external usb3.0 ssd if they don't have the resources/money to do it on their own computer.

The restrictions would therefore be limited only to the computers in class and they may do whatever they like on their private computers.

Requirements in a nutshell: create, encrypt, decrypt and mount a volume on classroom computers without root access

Alternative approaches to a solution of this problem are very much welcome!

Comment: Would "sudo" not allow you to let them execute only those commands as root, that you consider necessary?

Comment: `udiskie` may work for you. It uses a daemon which interacts with DBus to allow users to mount removable media. In addition it has built-in support for LUKS containers: https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie

Answer (score 0):

Use [encfs](http://www.arg0.net/encfs) as

```
   create the filesystem:

       % encfs ~/.crypt ~/crypt
       Directory "/home/me/.crypt" does not exist, create (y,n)?y
       Directory "/home/me/crypt" does not exist, create (y,n)?y
       Creating new encrypted volume.
       Please choose from one of the following options:
        enter "x" for expert configuration mode,
        enter "p" for pre-configured paranoia mode,
        anything else, or an empty line will select standard mode.
       ?>

       Standard configuration selected.
       Using cipher Blowfish, key size 160, block size 512
       New Password: <password entered here>
       Verify: <password entered here>

   The filesystem is now mounted and visible in ~/crypt.  If files are
   created there, they can be seen in encrypted form in ~/.crypt.  To
   unmount the filesystem, use fusermount with the -u (unmount) option:

       % fusermount -u ~/crypt
```

-- from its manual.

[fuse](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki) is required.

Answer (score 0):

Could use LUKS and only allow access to `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen [USB] userluks` and `luksClose` & `luksFormat`.

If the USB will always be the same device (or one of a number) you can specify them all, like:

> user ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /sbin/cryptsetup -v luksFormat /dev/sdc1,/sbin/cryptsetup -v luksOpen /dev/sdc1 userluks,/sbin/cryptsetup -v luksOpen /dev/sdd1 userluks,/sbin/cryptsetup -v luksOpen /dev/sde1 userluks,sbin/cryptsetup -v luksClose userluks

If the devices have been formatted somewhere else, and you know the specific user's device UUID, you can specify it instead of a device, something like this in `/etc/sudoers`:

> user ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /sbin/cryptsetup -v luksOpen UUID=xyz userluks

Shorter alias commands might be easier to type without mistakes too, and depending on your mount permissions associated mount commands might be required.

Could also use a custom sudo wrapper for more customized device access, [briefly mentioned here](https://serverfault.com/questions/510231/sudo-how-to-allow-only-one-argument-to-a-command).